# Action of $Homeo(S)$ on $Out(\pi_1(S))$ for $S$ orientable surface

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Let $S$ an orientable surface of any genus, possibly punctured and with boundary: with the classical notation $S=S_{g,n}^{b}$ where $g$ is the genus, $n$ the number of punctures and $b$ the numer of boundaries.

There is a well known morphism $\Psi \colon Homeo(S) \rightarrow Out(\pi_1(S))$ associating to an homeorphism $f$ the equivalence class of the map $\psi_f \in Aut(\pi_1(S))$ taking the class $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(S)$ to $[f(\gamma)]$.

This map descends to a morphism $\Psi \colon Mod(S) \rightarrow Out(\pi_1(S))$ which is more studied in geometric group theory, but now we are interseted in the first.

I need an example where this map $\Psi \colon Homeo(S) \rightarrow Out(\pi_1(S))$ is not surjective. If we considered only orientation perserving homemorphisms then the question would reduce to the study of the mapping class group action on $Out(\pi_1(S))$, but we consider even orientation reversing homeomorphisms.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $\psi_f\in$Aut is not well-defined. It's only well-defined when $f$ fixes the base-point $x$ over which $\pi_1$ is defined. So we have a homomorphism $Homeo(S)_x\to Aut(\pi_1(S,x))$. If $f$ is an arbitrary self-homeomorphism of $S$, then it is freely homotopic to some $f'$ fixing $x$, but the class of based homotopy of $f'$ is not uniquely determined, nor is its image $\psi_{f'}$. However the image of $\psi_{f'}$ in $\mathrm{Out}(\pi_1(S,x))$ does not depend on the choice of $f'$ and only depends on $f$.